# Problem reading data from ESP32 to Python

Tags: python, arduino, esp32

I have a problem, I am trying to read a code made on Arduino IDE over a ESP32, but the printed data shows as *b''* I have tried the same code with and Arduino UNO instead of ESP32 and it worked fine. This is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Mar  5 20:28:19 2021

@author: Andres
"""
import serial

arduino = serial.Serial('COM8', baudrate=115200, timeout=1.0)

    
while(True):
  line = arduino.readline().decode('utf-8')
  print(line)
```

This is ESP32 code (just sending numbers by serial port):

```
int16_t x=33;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

Serial.println(x);
delay(100);

x=x+1;
if(x==97)
{
x=32;
}

}
```

I must say that i have tried withe baudrate 9600 and 115200.
I have tried in other computer and changing the name of the port, but it didn't work.

Comment: You've triple checked that it's COM8, and that the serial port baudrate is 9600?

Comment: This is the code running on PC side? You need to add the ESP32 code also, otherwise we can't help you. Please have a look at how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TimRoberts, yes, and I have tried wirh different baudrates and tried in other pc with other COM. But it does not work.

Comment: @Tarmo  yes, it is running on PC side, i have tried different ideas in the ESP32 code, like this:
( I will edit the question with the ESP32 code)

Comment: At arduino serial monitor, can you see the log?, try with `Serial.println("hello string")`;

Comment: When you say *"the data shows as b''"*, you mean it is an empty **bytes** variable?

Comment: @WangLiang yes, the Arduino Serial monitor shows the data that I am printing with Serial.print() Serial.println() and Serial.write(). nonetheless, it does not work in python (I am using spyder)

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes that's right.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set **RTS** and **DTR** to `False` before opening the port:

```py
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = 'COM11'
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.setDTR(False)
ser.setRTS(False)

ser.open()

while True:
    b = ser.readline()
    print(b)
```

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know that DTR and RTS was stuff done through serial directly, and just assumed it was part of the flashing process when pushing software to the device. Thanks for pointing that out, as I've been working on this issue for an hour.